# What is Gov 2.0? And how can I implement the same in my website?

Tags: web-services

One of my clients has asked me to implement `Gov 2.0` in their website. Basically I don't have any idea about this and I am hearing the term `Gov 2.0` for the very first time. I did some research and googled and found that its a product/stuff of Microsoft and something related to government websites and social media.

Could anyone please tell me what actually this is?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you should ask your client to explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gov 2.0 is actually a US government initiative to expose data publicly on the web.

Here is a presentation that might help you with the concept:

http://www.cendi.gov/presentations/05_12_11_Holm.pdf

This is not strictly technical initiative per say, but I suspect that your client would like to expose their web apis and data sets on the web using RESTful web services.

Hope this helps.